# How to display only label but not the axis markings using Google Line Chart?

Tags: charts

I have a problem with Google chart URL. The URL is used to display a Google Chart to represent value(y axis) verses time(x axis). Y axis is indexed from 0 to 100 and labeled as "Value", Similarly X axis is indexed from 0 to 100 and labeled as "Time".

The URL is "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=300x300&chxt=y&chxt=x,x,y,y&chxl=1:|Time|3:|Value&chxp=1,50|3,50&chd=t:" In this Graph I need to display only the label and remove indexes. I tried all sorts of permutations and combinations. Please help !

Comment: You use deprecated Image Charts. There are new javascript charts that should be used instead.

Comment: Hey Vorrtex, can u give me some coding example please...